# How to create multipe column on ajax auto complete?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I create a table for searching items on ajax auto complete, I want to design like that(Table-1):

[image]

There is my web service code:

```
[WebMethod]
    public object[] GetResult(string prefixText, int count)
    {
        List<object> result;

        result = new List<object>();
        try
        {

            Some Database query...


            while (rd.Read())
            {

                result.Add(new
                {
                    ProductName = rd[0],
                    Pic= rd[1],
                    RecID = rd[2],
                    Properties= rd[3]
                });
            }
            rd.Close();
            con.Close();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {


        }
        return result.ToArray();
    }
```

I add a List object for all data and its java script side:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function onPopulated() {

          var list = $find("ace").get_completionList();
          var count = list.childNodes.length;
          for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {

              var item = list.childNodes[i]._value;
              var name = item.ProductName ;
              var kategory = item.Properties;
              var RecID = item.RecID;
              var Pic= item.Pic;
              var url = "http://abc.com.tr/img/p_" + RecID + "_" + Pic+ "_01.jpg"
              list.childNodes[i].innerHTML = '<span id="name"><table><tr style="width:260px;height:55px;" ><td><img width="50" height="50" style="position:relative;" src="' + url + '"/></td><td style="font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;min-height:20px;">'+ name + '</td></tr></table></span>';
              //'<span id="name"><table  style="width:260px;"><tr><td><img width="50" height="50" src="' + url + '"/></td><td><b style="font-size:12px;">' + name + '</b><br>' + kategory + '</td></tr></table></span>'
          }

      }


      function onSelected() {

          var i = $find("ace")._selectIndex;

          var item = list.get_completionList().childNodes[i]._value;

          $get("txtSearch").value = item.name;

      }

    </script>
```

i add a table it view like that(Table-2):
[image]

and finally its my ajax toolkit tag:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSearch" Width="261" />
        <cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ID="txtSearch_AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server"
DelimiterCharacters="" Enabled="True" ServicePath="WebService.asmx"
            FirstRowSelected="true"
             EnableCaching="false"
            ServiceMethod="GetResult"
MinimumPrefixLength="1"
       CompletionListCssClass="completionList"
     CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="itemHighlighted"
     CompletionListItemCssClass="listItem"
OnClientItemSelected="onSelected" OnClientPopulated="onPopulated"
            BehaviorID="ace" TargetControlID="txtSearch">
        </cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

**How to create table like  table-1? Please help me Thanks for your answers**

Answer (score 1):

I think, the following link may help you : http://vincexu.blogspot.com/2009/01/custom-autocomplete-6-multicolumn.html

For the record pasting code from the above mentioned article.

**ASPX**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="../Default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style>
    .cloumnspan
    {
        width:35px;
        padding:0px;
        border-color:Black;
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:1px;

    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1"  runat="server">
        <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1" />

           <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="myTextBox" Width="300" autocomplete="off" />
            <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender
                runat="server"  OnClientPopulated="dd" OnClientItemSelected="itemSelected"
                BehaviorID="AutoCompleteEx"
                ID="autoComplete1" 
                TargetControlID="myTextBox"
                ServicePath="AutoComplete.asmx" 
                ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList5"
                MinimumPrefixLength="2" 
                CompletionInterval="1000"
                EnableCaching="true" 
                CompletionSetCount="8"
                CompletionListCssClass="autocomplete_completionListElement" 
                CompletionListItemCssClass="autocomplete_listItem" 
                CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="autocomplete_highlightedListItem"
                DelimiterCharacters=";, :">
            </ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>

    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function itemSelected(ev)
{
    var index=$find("AutoCompleteEx")._selectIndex;
    var value=$find("AutoCompleteEx").get_completionList().childNodes[index]._value;
    $find("AutoCompleteEx").get_element().value = value;
}
function dd()
{
    var comletionList=$find("AutoCompleteEx").get_completionList();
    for(i=0;i<comletionList.childNodes.length;i++) {
        var itemobj=new Object();
        var _data = comletionList.childNodes[i]._value;
        itemobj.name= _data.substring(_data.lastIndexOf('|') + 1); // parse name as item value
        comletionList.childNodes[i]._value = itemobj.name;
        _data = _data.substring(0, _data.lastIndexOf('|'));
        itemobj.age = _data.substring(_data.lastIndexOf('|') + 1);
        _data = _data.substring(0, _data.lastIndexOf('|'));
        itemobj.id = _data.substring(_data.lastIndexOf('|') + 1);


        comletionList.childNodes[i].innerHTML = "<div class='cloumnspan' style='width:10%;float:left'>" + itemobj.id + "</div>"
                                              + "<div class='cloumnspan' style='width:70%;float:left'>" + itemobj.name + "</div>"
                                              + "<div class='cloumnspan' style='width:18%;'>" + itemobj.age + "</div>";

    }

}



</script>
</body>
```

Web Method:

```
[WebMethod]
public string[] GetCompletionList5(string prefixText, int count)
{

    if (count == 0)
    {
        count = 10;
    }

    if (prefixText.Equals("xyz"))
    {
        return new string[0];
    }

    Random random = new Random();
    List<string> items = new List<string>(count);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {

        char c1 = (char)random.Next(65, 90);
        char c2 = (char)random.Next(97, 122);
        char c3 = (char)random.Next(97, 122);
        int id = i;
        int age = random.Next(18, 70);
        items.Add(id.ToString() + "|" + age.ToString() + "|" + prefixText + c1 + c2 + c3);
    }

    return items.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer I did it from css like "width=300px !important" ,adding  autocomplete_completionListElement div

Comment: (Note, I am not flagging this yet since it has the key answer, but...) While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.